# Submit in Fine Uploader without a file

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, fine-uploader

I have fine uploader that I am using to upload a file and submit form data at the same time.

I would like to have an edit option where it would allow you to change the form data with or without changing the file.  So, is it possible to have Fine Uploader submit without requiring a file be submitted along with the form data.

Answer (score 0):

No, Fine Uploader is not a general-purpose library.  It deals specifically with cross-browser uploading, and it's complex enough without branching out into other areas.  If you'd like to submit a form without file data, it's really easy to do this cross-browser, no library required.  Without knowing more about your web app, I can't provide a more detailed answer.  If you'd like to request a feature, please do so in the Fine Uploader Github repository's issue tracker.  If you take this route, please describe your use case in detail.